# Angular 2: Adding ngClass to the element based on the click event

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I want Clicked class to be applied only to one clicked element at a time. Upon clicking other element the first clicked element should not have that class any more. It should be somewhat like this.clicked to that particular element.
[image: Click here for the desired output]

```css
  .rangeContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    }
    .range{
      height: 42px;
      background-color: #F6F6F6;
      color: #035688;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 800;
      line-height: 46px;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .clicked{
      background-color: white;
      color: #7A232E;
      border-top: 6px solid #7A232E;
    }
  
I want the
```

```html
   
<div class="rangeContainer">
    <span (click)="click = !click" [ngClass]="{'clicked' : click}" class="range">K4 - K5</span>
    <span (click)="click = !click" [ngClass]="{'clicked' : click}"class="range">1ST - 2ND</span>
    <span (click)="click = !click" [ngClass]="{'clicked' : click}"class="range">3RD - 4TH</span>
    <span (click)="click = !click" [ngClass]="{'clicked' : click}"class="range">5TH - 8TH</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<span
  *ngFor="let range of ['K4 - K5', '1ST - 2ND', '3RD - 4TH', '5TH - 8TH']; let i = index"
  (click)="activeIndex = i"
  [ngClass]="{ clicked : activeIndex === i }" class="range" >
  {{ range }}
</span>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/X3ZjcfFIfl5bwUfaJsZA?p=preview)**

Comment: is there a way to deactivate the class on click outside? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Amazing!! If you don't mind can u plz explain what does $event.stopPropagation() do and can I use it anywhere. I have used (click)="function($event)" but never used $event.stopPropagation().

Comment: The problem with this code is it doesn't stop listening to the host event even if I click outside. The desired effect would be to stop listening to the click event once clicked outside of the element. I have added console statement to the HostListener for your reference. https://plnkr.co/edit/3v3nFL?p=preview

Comment: another approach is using `Renderer` https://plnkr.co/edit/u7Lwn6?p=preview

Comment: I badly wanted to but I need at-least 15 reputation points and right now I have 12 so I am unable to ...It did solve my problem and I will upvote it as soon as I reach 15.

Comment: Hello @yurzui can u plz help me with this example. In this example, I want the click outside to unselect by default and then once unselected it should unsubscribe the listener. Right now you have to click on one of the menu item in order to be able to detect click outside. Please help...  plnkr.co/edit/lx9eBU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In component:

```
// Insert your real labels here
this.items = [{label: 'item 1'}, {label: 'item 2'}];
```

Then use a `*ngFor`:

```
<div class="rangeContainer">
    <span *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="toggleClick(item)" [ngClass]="{'clicked' :item.isClicked}" class="range">{{item.label}}</span>
</div>
```

Then toggle like this:

```
toggleClick(clickedItem: any): void {

  for (let item of items) {
    item.isClicked = false;
  }

  clickedItem.isClicked = true;
}
```

This will ensure only 1 item is clicked at one time. I'm using a loop so I can store that clicked state on the object instead. It makes life easier.